# MySQL query with complex sorting

Tags: mysql

We have such table in MySQL: id - int; title - varchar; hd - tinyint; source - tinyint; active - tinyint;

How do i get data from database with such sorting:

```
1. hd >= 3 AND source <> 5
2. hd >= 3 AND source = 5
3. hd = 2
4. other, i.e. hd < 2
```

Please show me how to do it properly and one sql query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when hd >= 3 AND source <> 5 then 1
              when hd >= 3 AND source = 5 then 2
              when hd = 2 then 3
              else 4
         end
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select * 
from table_name
order by case when hd >= 3 AND source <> 5 then 1
              when hd >= 3 AND source = 5 then 2
              when hd = 2 then 3
              else 4
         end
```